# using a javascript function inside another js file

Tags: javascript, html

i'm following along a book and I have 2 javascript files. Both are in the HTML file as:

```
<script src="playlist_store.js"></script>
<script src="playlist.js"></script>
```

however, when I try to call a function from playlist_store.js inside of playlist.js chrome debugger says "uncaught reference error. loadPlaylist is not defined.  loadPlaylist() is the function from playlist_store.js

I thought there might be a typo somewhere but I don't think there is. Does playlist.js actually need to somehow import or include / require  the playlist_store.js ?  Is the browser not smart enough to somehow link them so the functions in one you can call from another?

Comment: order of loading the files? does it help if you reverse the includes?

Comment: the function in playlist_store.js may be not in the global scope.

Comment: Post the code in `playlist_store.js`. You don't have to do any importing. If `loadPlaylist` is actually defined as a function in reachable scope, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a function like follows

```
function myaction () { }
```

is a *named* (private) function.
It is better to write a (private) function assigned to a variable:

```
var myaction = function () { };
```

Now what you need is a function, that is assigned to a variable in the global object:

```
myaction = function () { };
// or strict:
window.myaction = function () { };
```

It is now a global (public) function, so you can use it outside of your defining .js.

Beware that the first example, a function statement doesn't have a semicolon. Using the function operator as in the other examples, you need a semicolon.

Comment: I defined the function like the first option function myaction() {}. Apparently though when I copied and pasted from the PDF file to expression, the "" quotes became different and it had some error which prevented the playlist_store.js from loading and caused the error. I found it in the chrome debugger. Thanks for the help!